# Definite integral to Contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

We know that integration from $0$ to $2 \pi$ of some trigonometric function can be converted to contour integration, can we do same for $0$ to $\pi$? Here contour won't be unit circle. If so then how?

Comment: So it will be a line integral integral over a path that isn't closed.  What is the problem with this?  I don't understand the point of the question.  Can you add some more details?

Comment: can you explain what you mean with "convert to contour integration" or give an example?